# Visual Studio WCF Client creates classes with missing properties, adds ExtensionData property instead

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, wcf-proxy

I have a WCFService that returns sundry types of Data in this kind of a way:

```
[DataContract( Name="Amazing", NameSpace="http://schemas.myorganisation.com/DataContract1")]
Public class AmazingDto
{
    [DataMember( Order=0, IsRequired=true )]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember( Order=0, IsRequired=true )]
    public bool IsAmazing { get; set; }

}
```

And then

```
[DataContract ( Name="GetAmazingListResponse", NameSpace="http://schemas.myorganisation.com/DataContract1")]
Public class GetAmazingListResponseDto
{
     [DataMember(Order=0, IsRequired-true, EmitDefaultValue=False)]
     public ICollection<AmazingDto> AmazingList{ get; set; }
}
```

Also

```
[DataContract(Name = "Response", Namespace = "http://schemas.myorganisation.com/DataContract1")]
public class ResponseDto<TData> : BaseResponseDto
{
    public ResponseDto();

    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
    public StatusDto Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public TData Data { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
public ResponseDto<GetAmazingListResponseDto> GetAmazingList()
{
      var response = new ResponseDto<GetAmazingListDto>
       {
            Status = new StatusDto { StatusResult = StatusResultEnum.Success },
            Data = new GetAmazingListResponseDto
                 {
                     AmazingList = new List<AmazingDto>
                      {
                           new AmazingDto { Name="Ponies", IsAmazing=true },
                           new AmazingDto { Name="Glenatron", IsAmazing=false }
                       }
                 }
       };
       return response;
}
```

Now when I make a call to that service using a tool like SoapUI I get exactly the response I might expect.

```
  <GetAmazingListResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.myorganisation.com/DataContract1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Status>
           <a:StatusResult>Success</a:StatusResult>
        </a:Status>
        <a:Data xmlns:b="http://schemas.myorganisation.com/DataContract1">
           <b:AmazingList>
              <b:Amazing>
                 <b:Name>Ponies</b:Name>
                 <b:IsAmazing>true</b:IsAmazing>
              </b:Amazing>
              <b:Amazing>
                 <b:Name>Glenatron</b:Name>
                 <b:IsAmazing>false</b:IsAmazing>
              </b:Amazing>
           </b:AmazingList>
        </a:Data>
     </GetAmazingListResult>
```

However, when I use Visual Studio 2010 to create a Service Reference and make a call like this:

```
var client= new FindoutAmazingnessServiceClient();
var response = client.GetAmazingList();
```

What I find is that `response` only has two properties, `Status` and `ExtensionData`. I have seen this described in other SE questions but the answer was always that something was missing a *DataContract* or *DataMember* on the data contracts. I definitely have those, so something else must be happening so that VS.Net can't see my classes. I have tried referencing the DTO library that contains these files and trying to configure the reference to match types with that library, but it makes no difference.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you specify an OperationContract anywhere?

Comment: Yup, the OperationContract is on the interface that the service class implements.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add [DataMember] to your data members. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is, as I am working against my own WCF service, to import the interfaces into my client and then use [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channelfactory.aspx) to set up the connection. This works very well in my scenario, but doesn't solve the problem I am raising with this question.